# image disappeared after while loop

Tags: php

I generate the png img by calling the other php file.

The first is :

```
echo '<table>';
$a = 1;
while ($a <=2) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['a'] = $a;
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<img src="http://localserver/pic.php"/>';
    echo '</td>';
    a++;
}
echo '</table>;
```

The pic.php

```
session_start();
$b = $_SESSION['a'];
if($a == $b) {
    Qrcode::png($link,false,"L",2,2);
}
```

Suppose when a = 1 , The would be an qrcode generated and shown on table row 1 and
 when a=2 , no qr will be generated, the above lines of pic.php will skip.

I can generate properly when I run it seperately( if $a == 1) , if($a ==2).

However when I do the while loop , looping $b= 1 then $b=2
The qrcode of the row 1(case if $a==1) disappeared.

Why this happened?

Comment: Is `http://localserver/pic.php` url giving any image?

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in this line. `$` missing in variable name.

```
a++;
```

It will be

```
$a++;
```

Also in

```
echo '</table>;
```

Will be

```
echo '</table>';
```

Your while loop will also be performed for `$a=2` as you have used `less than or equal` condition. To perform only for `$a = 1` change condition to

```
while ($a <=1)
```

Also session_start() should be at top of the file.

```
session_start(); // move this
echo '<table>';
$a = 1;
while ($a <=2) {

    $_SESSION['a'] = $a;
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<img src="http://localserver/pic.php"/>';
    echo '</td>';
    $a++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

And

```
session_start(); // add this
$b = $_SESSION['a'];
if($a == $b) {
    Qrcode::png($link,false,"L",2,2);
}
```

Comment: I still cant solve it, the img for $a = 1 still no show. 
Yes , I need to perfrom $a = 2 also

Comment: still cant even I added header('Content-Type: image/png');

Answer (score 0):

your a++ at line 10 doesn't have $ symbol, hence its not taking it as variable. Make the code as below

```
session_start(); // you need to run session start only once, not required to run it in loop
echo '<table>';
$a = 1;
while ($a <=2) {
    $_SESSION['a'] = $a;
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<img src="http://localserver/pic.php"/>';
    echo '</td>';
    $a++;
}
echo '</table>';
```